# Архивирование папки в python

Tags: python, изображения

Работаю в Google Colab. Моей целью является обработка огромного количества картинок .jpg (169к изображений), а затем создание архива с ними. Возникла проблема с архивацией. Мой код выглядит вот так:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('test', 'zip', '/content/drive/MyDrive/cropped2/test_data')
```

Но архивирование продолжалось 2 часа, а потом колаб перезагрузился и все сломалось. Подскажите, пожалуйста, наиболее оптимальный способ архивирования папки в питон, пригодный для большого объема данных и колаба.

Comment: Честно говоря я не знаю лучшего способа архивировать и предполагаю, что его нет. Попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: @Sergey, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Сжимать JPEG картинки бесполезно - сэкономите пару процентов в лучшем случае и потратите тучу времени. Лучше архивировать **без сжатия**.

Например так:

```
shutil.make_archive('test', 'tar', '/content/drive/MyDrive/cropped2/test_data')
```